# Timer not synchronizing when running on multiple browsers or devices

Tags: javascript, angular, timer

I have created a timer which is not synchronizing on multiple browsers. On inactive tabs of browsers or even on devices timer is running faster or slower.. 
There is difference of 3-4 seconds on different tabs.. How to sync them?

This is my module code:

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
export class RAFTimer {
    public currentFrameId: number;
    public startTime: number;
    public numbers: BehaviorSubject<number>;
    constructor() {
        this._raf();
        this.numbers = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
        this.startTime = 0;
    }

    private _raf() {
        this.currentFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(timestamp => this._nextFrame(timestamp));
      }
      private _nextFrame(timestamp: number) {
        if ( this.startTime == 0) {
            this.startTime = timestamp;
        }
        const diff: number = timestamp - this.startTime;
        if ( diff > 100) {
           const n: number = Math.round(diff / 100);
          this.startTime = timestamp;
          this.numbers.next(n);
        }
        this._raf();
      }
      cancel() {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.currentFrameId);
        this.currentFrameId = null;
      }
}
```

This is the component code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { RAFTimer } from './raftimer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app';
  public timeInterval:number=10;
  public timeLeft:number=10000;
  constructor(private timer:RAFTimer) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let countNumber=1;
    let auctiontimer = this.timer.numbers.subscribe(
      (val) => {
          countNumber = countNumber+val;
          if(countNumber >= this.timeInterval) {
            this.timeLeft = this.timeLeft-countNumber/this.timeInterval;
            if(this.timeLeft<0) {
                this.timeLeft= 0;
            }
              countNumber=1;
          }
  }); 
  }

}
```

Please run this url on two different tabs together and you will note the difference in few seconds or within 1 minute..
https://angular-timer-raf.stackblitz.io/

If you want you can also edit these lines of code by opening this url==>

URL [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-timer-raf](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-timer-raf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I also know that when browser becomes inactive then timer goes slow, I have searched many things but none is working for me. But I need to synchronize timer any how.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you need to synchronize things in realtime between multiple clients, you will need to contact some kind of a backend (for seconds-precise things probably with websockets as communication protocol)

Comment: yes i need to synchronize things in realtime between clients. I am using loopback for backend... But problem is timer is running with difference in all browsers, how shall i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made an external (I hope either global or auction-specific) service for getting the time left  and you get an observable from that service. Good, I would do the same! But I think you should remove that "RequestAnimationFrame" from the service. My guess is that you are using it to update the view. You should not do that. RequestAnimationFrame, just like "setTimeout()" is a method that relies on the JS-engine to call that method asynchronously at some time. And before that happens, the thread might be blocked by some View-layer operations.

So instead you should let Angular itself handle View-updates, for example like this: `<div>Time: {{timer.numbers | async}}</div>` (async pipe automatically triggers changedetection on every new value).

If this doesn't help (is not precise enough), you might consider moving the timer-service on a completely different thread (a WebWorker in the browser)

You can also utilize a backend to synchronize your RAFTimer-Service every ... seconds. With REST, you would do that by making a request every ... seconds asking for the current time and other auction information; I assume you are making an auction/bidding app. With websockets you would do that by making the backend-service push that information to the client on every update/interval.

Comment: thanks for help, you have provided me good idea.. i will try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution finally. This is the final code which will sync timer in all browsers.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timer',
  templateUrl: './timer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timer.component.css']
})
export class TimerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() futureDateTime: string;
  public diff: number;
  public timeLeft: string;
  private $counter: Observable<number>;
  private subscription: Subscription;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.countdown();
  }
  countdown() {
    // endDateTime YYYY-mm-dd H:m:s
    const endDateTime = new Date(this.futureDateTime);
    let currentDate = new Date().getTime();
    //  Get difference in milliseconds between current date and future date ...
    let diffInMillSeconds = this.getDiffInMillSeconds(currentDate, endDateTime);
    diffInMillSeconds = diffInMillSeconds + 1000;
    this.$counter = Observable.interval(1000).map((x) => {
      currentDate = new Date().getTime();
      this.diff = Math.floor((endDateTime.getTime() - currentDate) / 1000);
      return x;
    }).takeUntil(Observable.timer(diffInMillSeconds));
    this.subscription = this.$counter.subscribe((x) => {
      if (this.diff === 0) {
        this.timeLeft = '0.0.0';
      } else if (this.diff > 0) {
        this.timeLeft = this.dhms(this.diff);
      }
    });
  }
  /**
   * @desc Function to get milli seconds between current date and future date
   */
  getDiffInMillSeconds(currentDate, futureDate) {
    const dif = currentDate - futureDate.getTime();
    const Seconds_from_T1_to_T2 = dif / 1000;
    const Seconds_Between_Dates = Math.abs(Seconds_from_T1_to_T2);
    const milliSeconds = Seconds_Between_Dates * 1000;
    return milliSeconds;
  }
  /**
   * @desc Function to calculate day, hours, minutes and seconds..
   */
  dhms(t) {
    let days, hours, minutes, seconds;
    days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
    t -= days * 86400;
    hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24;
    t -= hours * 3600;
    minutes = Math.floor(t / 60) % 60;
    t -= minutes * 60;
    seconds = t % 60;
    return [
      // days + 'd',
      hours + '.',
      minutes + '.',
      seconds
    ].join(' ');
  }
}
```